# bash : cannot execute binary file

Tags: makefile

after building the project with a gnumake, I looked on the internet and executed

`sudo chmod +x filename`

afterwards, I cannot execute the file and gets the error

`-bash : ./filename cannot execute binary file`

I compiled it on the same device as the one that I am executing it in.

Comment: What command are you using to execute it?

Comment: You can check some information about your file with `file filename`. If it's a compiled binary this should tell you something like `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)...`. And if your target architecture is different you'll know why it cannot be executed.

Comment: I've hit it once when the code was compiled in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine, but no 32-bit runtime support was enabled (no 32-bit runtime linker).